Continuous $f$ so that $f(x)$, $f(x) + \sqrt{2}$, $f(x) + x$ $\in \mathbb{Q}^c$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$
Does there exist a continuous function $ f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that
$$
f(x),f(x) + \sqrt{2}  , f(x) + x
$$
are in $\mathbb{Q}^c$ for all $ x \in \mathbb{Q}^c $? Here, $ \mathbb{Q}^c $ denotes the set of irrational numbers.
This problem was originally posed to me by a friend, yesterday. We didn't reach to an answer, so we decided to post it here.

I think, it is possible to construct a strictly increasing continuous bijective function $f$ such that for every rational $q$ the values $q$, $q-\sqrt{2}$ of $f$ and $q$ of $f(x) +x$ are obtained on rational points. Simply enumerate all rational points and on $n$-th step define finitely many values of $f$ in rational points (say, $f$ on $n$-th step is defined on a finite set $\Delta_n$) so that
(i) the above properties hold for the $n$-th rational point,
(ii) $\min \Delta_n<-n$, $\max \Delta_n>n$;
(iii) the difference between every two consecutive elements of $\Delta_n$, and the difference between consecutive values of $f$ on $\Delta_n$ is at most $1/n$.
As a result, you get the restriction of $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ which defines $f$ itself by continuity.

How do we know we can give $f$ the value $f(x)=q-x$ somewhere without destroying the monotonicity?

@ChristianRemling if $a+f(a)<q<b+f(b) $ for consecutive $a<b$ in $\Delta_{n-1}$, we can choose rational $c\in (a, b)$ and $w\in (f(a), f(b))$ with $c+w=q$, put $c$ to $\Delta_n$ and define $f(c)=w$.
